# Giving a method as a callback function (gcc 4.7.1)

Tags: c++, callback, gcc4.7

I'm trying to set a seemingly-simple callback method pointer into a variable and get the following error:

> CSerialSniffer.cpp|11|error: cannot convert
>   ‘CSerialSniffer::AsyncRecieverReceived’ from type
>   ‘Nexus::TReceiveCallback (CSerialSniffer::)(Nexus::CData*,
>   Nexus::IMetaData*)’}’| to type ‘Nexus::typeAsyncReceiverCallback {aka
>   Nexus::TReceiveCallback (*)(Nexus::CData*, Nexus::IMetaData*)}’|

Here is the set statement:

```
typeAsyncReceiverCallback l_pPointer = AsyncRecieverReceived;
```

And I have the following defined:

```
typedef TReceiveCallback (*typeAsyncReceiverCallback)(CData *a_pData, IMetaData *a_pMetaData);

class CSerialSniffer
{
...
public:
    Nexus::TReceiveCallback AsyncRecieverReceived(Nexus::CData *a_pData, Nexus::IMetaData *a_pMetaData);
...
}
```

I've been at this for hours now, any ideas?

**In response to answers:**
I have the same callback mechanism here:

```
typedef void (*EnqueueCallback)( PData *pd );

class SomeClass
{
...
public:
   void enqueue( PData *pd );
...
};


class CSerialSniffer
{
...
public:
    void set_enqueue_callback(EnqueueCallback a_pEnqueueCallback );
...
}


SomeClass::SomeFunction(){
 this->serialSniffer->set_enqueue_callback(this->enqueue);
}
```

And it compiles well.
What's the difference between the two?

Comment: It's very very strange that the latter would compile.  Are you sure it is compiled at all?

Comment: Well. It doesn't output any errors, but the project doesn't compile on its whole yet. I'll verify that

Comment: http://codepad.org/Lcw6kgpi - it doesn't compile here.

Comment: OK. Finally mangaed to compile the damn project. You're right! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CSerialSniffer::AsyncRecieverReceived` is a member function.  It cannot be used without an object, so either you make it a free function (outside the class), or a static function:

```
class CSerialSniffer
{
...
public:
    static Nexus::TReceiveCallback AsyncRecieverReceived(
         Nexus::CData *a_pData, 
         Nexus::IMetaData *a_pMetaData);
...
};

typeAsyncReceiverCallback l_pPointer = &CSerialSniffer::AsyncRecieverReceived;
```

A better alternative with C++11 is to use a `std::function<>` instead:

```
typedef std::function<TReceiveCallback(CData*,IMetaData*)> 
        typeAsyncReceiverCallback;
```

Now you can create a free function by binding an object as the first argument of the member function:

```
CSerialSniffer snivver;

auto callback = std::bind( 
     std::mem_fun( &CSerialSniffer::AsyncRecieverReceived ),
     &snivver );
```

These goodies are in ther `<functional>` header.

Answer (score 2):

Your callback declaration

`typeAsyncReceiverCallback`

is regular function, but

`AsyncReceiverReceived`

is a method (i.e. it NEEDS "this" pointer and there's no way it can get it this way in c++).

Either change `AsyncReceiverReceived` to static or use the observer pattern.